# Does drawableStart converts to drawableLeft on older devices?

Tags: android-layout, right-to-left

I am getting tons of Lint warning to change layout to better support RTL devices.

If I use `drawableStart` in XML, what will happen in the devices that came before this attribute was introduced? Will they silently convert it to `drawableLeft` or the app will break?

I have good experience with using unsupported themes which silently convert to supported theme if my theme is not supported (like usage of Holo theme explicitly). So I wonder if the same will happen with these attributes.

For example, a device with SDK 10 uses this app. Will it crash or not as `drawableStart` was not known at that time?

PS. I do not have a device with SDK 10 to test the real behaviour, just emulators. That is why I am reluctant to believe what emulator says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) you *should* use both start and left.

I have tried to use only `start/end` on API 16 and the behaved exactly as you would expect -- `start` got mapped to `left` and `end` got mapped to `right`.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I asked. What if a device with sdk 10 opens the app. Will it crash or not?!

Comment: RTL support was added in API 17, I guess the bahavior for API 16 and API 10 will be the same

Comment: Yes, it would. It this a device or emulator you tested on?

Comment: Actually, that links says something that I've just noticed, after seeing it dozens of time. We should use BOTH. This is not only a great advice, but also proves that the app will not crash on these attributes.